# Problems with a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, exception

I´ve been trying to add some lines of a .csv document to a SQL Database ,but in a point i get this exception:

```
SYSTEM.FORMATEXCEPTION: STRING '0000-00-00 00:00:01' WAS NOT RECOGNIZED AS A VALID DATETIME.
AT SYSTEM.DATETIMEPARSE.PARSE(READONLYSPAN`1 S, DATETIMEFORMATINFO DTFI, DATETIMESTYLES STYLES)
AT SYSTEM.DATETIME.PARSE(STRING S)
AT FRAME2020.OBJETOSERVICIOS.DEVOLVERSERVICIOS(STRING[] LISTA) IN 
D:\TRABAJO\FRAME2020\FRAME2020\CONEXIONBDD.CS:LINE
```

And i dont know how to solve it , i tried with try/except but it doesnt work with my approach  ,any recommendations?

Comment: Can you please show a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem? By the way, `DateTime.MinValue` is `00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001` in the Gregorian calendar, so, your `0000-00-00 00:00:01` value does _not_ seems a valid `DateTime`.

Comment: WHILE EXCEPTION MESSAGES ARE LOCALIZED, I'M NOT AWARE OF ANY SETTING THAT WOULD RENDER THEM IN ALL CAPS, SO I WONDER HOW THAT CAME ABOUT.

Comment: I believe it is beccause the DateTime minimal value in SQL is something about 1770 year or so. So you can not insert a date with a year = 0000.

Comment: @VDN exception is form .net parser not SQL. So SQL values in this case are irrelevant

Comment: Sorry about not showing any code! And thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your date which you try to set: `0000-00-00 00:00:01`, there isn't day 0, month 0 and year 0.
Minimal `DateTime` is `1-1-0001 00:00:00`

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed us any code, so I'm making some assumptions here. It looks like you're using `DateTime.Parse` to parse a column in your `csv` source that you expect to be a `DateTime`. However, your source has values in that column which do not parse into a valid `DateTime`. Such as `0000-00-00 00:00:01`.

Others have already pointed out that `0000-00-00 00:00:01` is not a valid `DateTime`. In order to address this issue, you can use a different method to parse that column. For example, [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse). This will attempt to parse a `string` into a `DateTime` and return `false` if it fails or `true` if it succeeds.

```
string s = "0000-00-00 00:00:01";
if (!DateTime.TryParse(s, out DateTime dt))
{
   // The string could not be parsed to a DateTime.
}
else
{
   // The string was successfully parsed and the variable dt will have the parsed
   // DateTime.
}
```

Then once you have that, you'll know if you successfully parsed the `string` into a `DateTime` and you can do something other than throw a `FormatException` when it fails.

Comment: Thanks and sorry about not showing any code at all , it was really helpful!